# Static Bitmap does not scale images correctly on different displays, Issue with CreateCompatibleBitmap

Tags: bitmap, mfc

I am working on a MFC Dialog Application compiled statically.

The dialog view has a static control to display a bitmap. When the user selects an item in a listbox, the bitmap is changed to a corresponding image. The default image is for item 1 and is defined in init-instance. It is displayed when the app starts. There are 9 selections with 9 different bitmap resource images, all bitmaps are the same size and resolution. When the user selects a different listbox item, a new bitmap is defined and CreateCompatibleBitmap function is called for the DC. A case statement loads the various resource images using the LoadBitmapW function. The static control is updated with the new bitmap.

Every thing works fine on my development system, refer to "Correct.png" which shows the position and size of the various bitmaps displayed. All 9 bitmaps diplayed are sized correctly.

Correct.png:
[image: Correct.PNG]

When I install the program on other machines, the initial bitmap is displayed in the correct size. When listbox selections are made, the new image displayed is not scaled correctly to match the original image size, even if I re-specify the static control position and size used initially. The subsequent image(s) are larger and clipped on systems with lower res displays (or maybe lower DPI). On systems with higher res 4k displays the subsequent images are smaller than the original default image. Images "Lower.png" and "Higher.png" show this.

Lower.png:
[image: Lower.png]

Higher.png
[image: Hgher.png]

Apparently, CreateCompatibleBitmap does not create a "compatible" bitmap as the relative size or scale is not the same as the original when the app is started.

I dont understand the cause or know how to correct this.

This code is in the ::OnLbnSelchange() function to swap bitmaps:

```
CBitmap bm; //Temp Bitmap
CDC* pDC = GetDC();
bm.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, m_XOver, m_YDown);

switch (m_Selection) {  //Select bitmap to display
case 0:
    bm.LoadBitmapW(IDB_Selection1);
    break;
case 1: 
    bm.LoadBitmapW(IDB_Selection2);
    break;
case 2: 
    bm.LoadBitmapW(IDB_Selection3);
    break;
    // additional 6 cases deleted for brevity
default:
    break;

// Re-specifying static control size and position didn't help problem
//reset size of window to match original in init-instance
CWnd* pDlg = GetDlgItem(IDC_Bitmap);
pDlg->SetWindowPos(NULL, m_Left, m_Top, m_XOver, m_YDown, 0);

HBITMAP prev = m_Bitmap.SetBitmap(bm.operator HBITMAP());   //swap bitmap image
if (NULL != prev)
{
    DeleteObject(prev);     //delete the previous bitmap
}
ReleaseDC(pDC);
UpdateData(FALSE);
```

Comment: Are you sure you could use CreateCompatibleBitmap and later LoadBitmap on the same object? It asserts.

Comment: No run time assertion errors or compiler errors. Program runs fine on the 6 systems I've tested it on. Just the noted issue re scaling of the image after the bitmap is changed.

Comment: If I call to CreateCompatibleBitmap as you provided and then LoadBitmapW on the same bm object, I get assert that the bitmap is already attached.

Comment: Specify `SS_REALSIZECONTROL` flag if you want the bitmap to match the control's bounding rectangle. Do that either in dialog editor, for static control's property, or use `ModifyStyle`

Comment: I have changed the property of the static control to Real Size Image. It had no impact on the problem. The first image is OK, subsequent images are over or under sized on different computers. Create Compatible Bitmap should compensate for the display resolution... Still works fine on my development system and identical models with the same graphics. The problem appears to be related to the DPI of  system, but then why would the initial image displayed be correct? it is only the subsequent images swapped that are scaled wrong.

Comment: Why doing around with CreateCompatibleBitmap()? I would just call m_Bitmap.LoadBitmap() and later draw it to the output DC (using either BitBlt() or StretchBlt()).

Comment: Nick, I would like to implement your solution as it appears much simpler.  Unfortunately CStatic member does not have a LoadBitmap() function were CBitmap does. 

Error: class "CStatic" has no member "LoadBitmapW"